# Jsoup 1.16.1 is throwing error with Jetty 11.0.15

Tags: jsoup

Jsoup 1.16.1 is throwing error with Jetty 11.0.15.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.11.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) on project jsoup: Compilation failure
[ERROR] ****jsoup/src/test/java/org/jsoup/integration/TestServer.java:[3,32] cannot access org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server
[ERROR]   bad cla[tag:tag-name]ss file: *****eclipse/jetty/jetty-server/11.0.15/jetty-server-11.0.15.jar(org/eclipse/jetty/server/Server.class)
[ERROR]     class file has wrong version 55.0, should be 52.0
[ERROR]     Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.
```

It works with 9.* version of Jetty

Answer (score 0):

> Yes, the jsoup tests require Jetty 9, because that is the last that supports Java 8 which we target.
> You can still use jsoup in a project with any later version of Jetty - just include a built jsoup jar (so that you don't get a version mismatch).

source: https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/issues/1961